# Why doesn't `transfer` method change balance?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, ethereumjs

I have a smart contract to deal with payment as below code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract PaymentChannel {
    address public sender;
    address public recipient;
    uint public expiration;
    // the total amount in this payment channel
    uint public totalAmount;
    uint public paidAmount;

    constructor(address _recipient, uint duration) payable {
        console.log("constructor", msg.sender, _recipient, duration);
        sender = msg.sender;
        recipient = _recipient;
        expiration = block.timestamp + duration;
        totalAmount = msg.value;
    }

    function pay(uint amount) external {
        console.log("pay", msg.sender, amount);
        require(msg.sender == sender, "Only recipient can close the channel");
        require(paidAmount + amount <= totalAmount, "Amount exceeds total");
        paidAmount += amount;
    }

    function confirmPayment() external payable {
        console.log("confirm payment", msg.sender);
        require(
            msg.sender == recipient,
            "Only recipient can confirm the payment"
        );
        require(paidAmount == totalAmount, "Payment is not complete");
        require(
            address(this).balance == paidAmount,
            "Balance on the contract is wrong"
        );
        payable(recipient).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

then I have unit test in `hardhat` like below:

```typescript
import { loadFixture } from '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox/network-helpers';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';

describe('Payment channel', function () {
  const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const oneHour = 3600;
  const expireAt = now + oneHour;
  const amount = ethers.parseEther('5');
  async function deployFixture() {
    const [owner, otherAccount] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const PaymentChannel = await ethers.getContractFactory('PaymentChannel');

    const [_, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const paymentChannel = await PaymentChannel.deploy(addr1, expireAt, { value: amount });
    return { paymentChannel, owner, otherAccount, recipient: addr1, addr2 };
  }

  it('should be able to confirm payment', async () => {
    const { paymentChannel, owner, recipient } = await loadFixture(deployFixture);
    const recipientContract = await paymentChannel.connect(recipient);
    await paymentChannel.pay(ethers.parseEther('1'));
    await paymentChannel.pay(ethers.parseEther('4'));
    console.log('balance before confirm', await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner));
    await recipientContract.confirmPayment();
    console.log('balance after confirm', await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner));
    expect(await paymentChannel.paidAmount()).to.equal(ethers.parseEther('5'));
    expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(paymentChannel.getAddress())).to.equal(0);
    expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(recipient.address)).to.equal(amount);
  });
```

As you can see, the unit test tries to pay 5 ether then calling `confirmPayment()` which calls the `payable(recipient).transfer(address(this).balance);`.

And the last line in the unit test fails on checking the `recipient` balance,

```
+ expected - actual

      -0
      +5000000000000000000
```

the error says that the balance on recipient's address is still `0`. But the previous line about checking contract's balance is already 0. I wonder what I am doing wrong in the contract?

Comment: yes, correct. it is a payment channel rather than a real payment. The real payment is made inside `confirmPayment` method.